# Python struct pack character size

Tags: python, character-encoding, size

Someone knows why 'c' (character) after packing, is using in first case 1 byte, and in the second case, uses 2 bytes and in the third case 8 bytes?

```
>>> from struct import pack
>>> pack('c','A');
'A'
>>> pack('ch','A',1);
'A\x00\x01\x00'
>>> pack('cQ','A',1);
'A\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

How to enforce character always to take 1 byte?

Comment: First parameter in pack function isn't what is packed. It is the format. Second, third and so on parameters are what is being packed. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack for more info. And follow this link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters to find out more about available formats.

Comment: @krzysiej Please submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem occurred because of byte alignment. To pack without alignment use '=' sign:

```
pack('=cQ','A',1);
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-strings ref 7.3.2.1